# Capture unprintable characters in Silverlight or WinForms field

Tags: .net, winforms, silverlight, inputstream, barcode-scanner

I have a Silverlight application. In one field the user is supposed to enter data by scanning a barcode using a usb connected barcode-scanner.

Normally this is not a problem because the barcode scanner behaves just like any keyboard.

But it seems Silverlight, WinForms, etc. are removing some unprintable characters. In my case I would like to capture the ASCII character 29 that I know exists on the barcode.

(If for example I make a Console program and do Console.Read() then I'm able to capture the ASCII 29.)

Any ideas?

Comment: What encoding are you using? You might need to specify unicode. Did you look into System.Text.Encoding class ?